# Gradle Copy task issue with duplicate file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In `build.gradle` I have the following code:

```
task copyModifiedSources(type:Copy) {
    from ('ApiClient.java.modified') {
        rename 'ApiClient.java.modified', 'ApiClient.java'
    }
    setDuplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE)
    into 'build/generated/src/main/java/com/client/invoker'
}
```

I am trying to copy `ApiClient.java.modified` (renamed to `ApiClient.java` before copy) file into `build/generated/src/main/java/com/client/invoker` folder which already has `ApiClient.java` file.
I am using a duplicate strategy to override `APIClient.java` from `/invoker` folder with `ApiClient.java.modified`.

If I rename the copying file to the file name not in `/invoker` folder, then it works but does not work with the duplicate file name. The file is not copied successfully.

Could you please help me to figure out what is going wrong?

```
Gradle -> 6.5.1
Java -> 11
```

Answer (score 1):

the `rename` is same level as from not under `from`.

below example final file in build/gen content is 'override'

```
task setupFiles() {
    doLast {
        mkdir 'build/override' 
        mkdir 'build/gen'
        new File('build/gen/ApiClient.java').text = "orig"
        new File('build/override/ApiClient.java.modified').text = "override"
    }
}

task copyModifiedSources(type: Copy, dependsOn: setupFiles) {
    from 'build/override'
    include '*.modified'
    rename '(.*).modified', '$1'

    setDuplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE)
    into 'build/gen'
}
```

run `gradle clean copyModifiedSources`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. duplicatesStrategy **did not check if destination directory has the same files** while copying the files from single source of directory. But duplicatesStrategy **checks if multiple sources** which are being copied into destination **have the same files or not**. If have then it will perform the action based on strategy. For example.

```
['warn', 'include', 'exclude', 'fail'].each { strategy ->
    task "copyDuplicatesStrategy${strategy.capitalize()}"(type: Copy) {

        def sourceFile = 'src/main/resources/Folder2/abc.txt'
        def destDir = 'src/main/resources/Folder1_'
        def finalOutput = "$destDir/abc.txt"

        from 'src/webroot'
        from sourceFile
        from 'src/manual'

        into "$destDir"

        // Only the value for this property differs for
        // each created task.
        duplicatesStrategy = strategy

        // Print the used duplicates strategy when
        // the task starts.
        doFirst {
            println "Copying with duplicates strategy '${strategy}'."
        }

        // Print the contents of the copied file COPY.txt.
        doLast {
            println "Contents of COPY.txt: Exist :: ${file(sourceFile).exists()}, Loc: ${file(sourceFile).getPath()}"
            println file(sourceFile).text

            println "Contents of COPY.txt: Exist :: ${file(finalOutput).exists()}, Loc: ${file(finalOutput).getPath()}"
            println file(finalOutput).text
        }
    }
}
```

For reference: https://blog.mrhaki.com/2015/04/gradle-goodness-handle-copying.html